# Port forwarding / XBIAN

Tags: raspi-config, ethernet-port, xbian, port-forwarding

I have UPNP enable on my router, its may be a bit (very) unsafe.
I'm worried now cause the raspberry PI have 3 port opened through UPNP 7000 TCP and UDP and 4433TCP

From what I know 4433 is a backdoor from a trojan, should I be worried?

Kind regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Backdoor.Acidoor` only infects Windows. Your pi should be safe.

Are you sure that the pi was the one who opened that port? Might be that one of your PCs are infected.

Comment: This make sense, yes the PI open though UPNP, at least that what my router tell me, I'm on OSX anyway so I should be ok, I just blocked this port from the router firewall anyway just to be in the safe side.